# CRM 2011: How to update 'Modified By' field of closed case

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm

I have a workflow which automatically close the case after 7 days. But because it resolved by a workflow, Case's `Last Modified By` field is set to process owner. For reporting I want to set the `Last Modified By` equal to Case owner.

Is there any way to do this?

I think CRm don't let us to update closed case so I can't do this with post-operation plugin.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to add a boolean field inside the case entity such as "Case Closed Automatically" and set it to true when the case is closed by the workflow.

In this way inside the report you can show the actual `Modified By` value for the cases closed manually, and the case owner for the cases closed automatically.

I know it's not the right answer, but it's easier to implement than a plugin or something else.

Comment: thanks, what is what I was thinking. For reporting, I think it will be good to create a new field called resolved by. Will update that field on case resolution.

Comment: if the workflow is triggered automatically maybe you need this custom wf activity to identify the correct user: http://www.crmanswers.net/2013/10/get-current-user-inside-workflow.html

Comment: Yes, but current user will be the Process Owner. I want Case owner to be Modified by at the time case is resolved. I have done it by adding a custom field, which is updated by plugin on pre-operation.